# Inputs of touchscreen mirrored when screen is flipped

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, display-rotation

My device is an inspiron 7306 2-in-1 convertible running Ubuntu 20.04

When rotating the device (e.g. upside down as in "tent" mode), the screen automatically flips. But then, touchscreen and touchpad inputs are mirrored on the x and y-axis. Touching the top left corner has an effect on the bottom right corner.

The mouse still moves exactly as it should.

This makes sense, Ubuntu probably mirrors input devices when the screen is rotated. This does make sense for the mouse, but not for the touchscreen.

I could not google any way on how to fix this.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?